# simple ruby reg ex for matching only one of three single characters

Tags: ruby, regex

I am looking for a simple ruby reg ex for matching one and only one of three characters.  for example:
"a" or "b" or "c" but not "ab", "ac", etc.

The ones I have tried /[abc]/ or /a|b|c/ do not work because they also match "ab", "ac", etc. according to rubular.com.  I also tried playing with ^ and $ placement but it did not work.

I am new to ruby and must be missing something simple.  Please help.  Thank you!

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this regexp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[1] pry(main)> "a" =~ /^[a-c]$/
=> 0
[2] pry(main)> "ac" =~ /^[a-c]$/
=> nil
```

But why not just use `==` if you specifically need to match a single character? If you need to *do* something with the character you could roll that all up and skip regex altogether.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes I can do something like: if ((str1 == "a" | str1 == "b" | str1 == "c") & (str2 == "a" | str2 == "b" | str2 == "c")) but I was just looking for a more concise way to write this.

Comment: rubular.com is what threw me off.  I had tried Dave Newton's suggest reg ex there and it showed "No match" for "a".  I am not sure why.  But it works fine at the ruby interpreter.

Comment: That's curious. I wish I could post a snapshot.  For mine it still says "no matches" http://rubular.com/r/frISIpatlb

Comment: @user1493570 Because you have quotes around it; there aren't any quotes in your regex.

Answer (score 0):

if all you want is to capture strings of repeating same characters you could try something like this

^([a]+|[b]+|[c]+)$